# How to make this String appears

Tags: java, android

How I can make the `String time` correctly appear in each marker, it's obtained from the JSON file as well as the name, description, lat/long, image URL of the marker, but the time is the only thing that does not appear  dynamically for each marker, instead it gets only one of the time string from the JSON and show the same time string in all markers, how could I do so that the respective time of each marker appears as it should?

I think that the problem is in `time = thing.gettime();` line, but I can't find out how to fix.

This is this part of my code, I really don't know what I can do to fix it.

```
for (int i = 0; i < thingslist.size(); i++) {
    Things thing = thingslist.get(i);
    googleMaps.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(Double.valueOf(thing.getLatitude()), Double.valueOf(thing.getLongitude())))
            .snippet(thing.getDescricao())
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(MudancaIconeMarker(thing.getTipo())))
            .title(thing.getName()))
            .setTag(thing.getPhoto());

    time = thing.getTime(); //this



}

googleMaps.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityDetails.class);

        ActivityDetails.Info.id = marker.getId();
        ActivityDetails.Info.photoURL = marker.getTag().toString();

        TabInfos.name = marker.getTitle();
        TabInfos.id = marker.getId();
        TabInfos.description = marker.getSnippet();
        TabInfos.time = time; // this

        for (int i = 0;i<24;i++ ){
            if (marker.getId().equals("m"+i)){ ActivityDetails.Info.num=i;TabInfos.num=i;}
        }
        TabMap.this.startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

**I also tried this, but didn't solved the issue:**

```
public void setTime(String time) {
    this.time = time;
}

public String getTime() {
    return time;
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMapas) {
for (int i = 0; i < thingslist.size(); i++) {
    Things thing = thingslist.get(i);
    googleMaps.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(Double.valueOf(thing.getLatitude()), Double.valueOf(thing.getLongitude())))
            .snippet(thing.getDescricao())
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(MudancaIconeMarker(thing.getTipo())))
            .title(thing.getName()))
            .setTag(thing.getPhoto());

        setTime(thing.getTime()); //here


}

googleMaps.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityDetails.class);

        ActivityDetails.Info.id = marker.getId();
        ActivityDetails.Info.photoURL = marker.getTag().toString();

        TabInfos.name = marker.getTitle();
        TabInfos.id = marker.getId();
        TabInfos.description = marker.getSnippet();
        AbaInfos.time = getTime();   //here


        for (int i = 0;i<24;i++ ){
            if (marker.getId().equals("m"+i)){ ActivityDetails.Info.num=i;TabInfos.num=i;}
        }
        TabMap.this.startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

***PS. All the variables were properly initialized/declared, since it have NO compilation/building errors, it compiles normally, the problem is what I asked in the question***

Comment: You are sharing a `time` field. Of course the time shown is going to be whatever time from the last `thing` in the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are several ways you can do that. one simple way is to use the **thingslist** in the `onInfoWindowClick` and use TAG for index of the **thingslist** like this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < thingslist.size(); i++) {
        Things thing = thingslist.get(i);
        googleMaps.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(Double.valueOf(thing.getLatitude()), Double.valueOf(thing.getLongitude())))
                .snippet(thing.getDescricao())
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(MudancaIconeMarker(thing.getTipo())))
                .title(thing.getName()))
                .setTag(String.valueOf(i));

    }

    googleMaps.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityDetails.class);
            int index=Integer.valueOf(marker.getTag());
            ActivityDetails.Info.id = marker.getId();
            ActivityDetails.Info.photoURL =thingslist.get(index).getPhoto(); 

            TabInfos.name = marker.getTitle();
            TabInfos.id = marker.getId();
            TabInfos.description = marker.getSnippet();
            TabInfos.time = thingslist.get(index).getTime();

            for (int i = 0;i<24;i++ ){
                if (marker.getId().equals("m"+i)){ ActivityDetails.Info.num=i;TabInfos.num=i;}
            }
            TabMap.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating a "time" field for your markers, you just have a global variable called "time". 
Shouldn't you have a thing like this?

```
 googleMaps.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().....setTime(thing.getTime()));
```

Comment: You should then set TabInfos.time = marker.getTime();

Comment: What i mean is add a field "time" to the marker and then modify it with a method setTime() to call on the added marker, just like you do with setTag(). Then you can call TabInfos.time = marker.getTime().

Comment: You didn't understand what @Agnohendrix has said. You do not have to use a unique field "time" for all your entries. You used setTime() ang getTime() method that write and read the class field. And on each "for" cycle, you overridden that value.. so you can see always the last entry.

Comment: Ok, setTime is not a method from the API you are using, Can you override it or create a class which extends it with the field "time"?

Comment: Hey, I already managed to fix the issue, thanks for trying to help! :)